# Needing background image to end repetition at start of footer

Tags: css

Basically, right now I have multiple images but only one at as a background image to my body (being a blue square) and I need to to end at the start of the footer, so underneath the footer is black but no matter what I do, it doesn't seem to help.

Here's an example http://bit.ly/1nKIee1 (on postimage)

I thought that maybe if I ended the body tag, then started the footer tag it wouldn't do it but that doesn't seem to fix anything.

CSS

```
.nav {
  background-image: url(image/top.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

body {
  background-image: url(image/blue.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: #000000;
}

footer {
  background-image: url(image/footer.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-color: #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px;
  padding: 45px;
}
```

Thanks in advance - Shy ♥

Comment: I recommend to post a working example here. If you cannot publish your development, try to make a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) which show your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't give background property to body instead of this use a div inside body upto footer and give these properties to that div for example

**HTML :**

```
<nav>......</nav>
<div class="container">......</div>
<footer>.........</footer>
```

**CSS :**

```
.nav {
  background-image: url(image/top.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

container {
  background-image: url(image/blue.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: #000000;
}

footer {
  background-image: url(image/footer.png);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-color: #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: #000000 1px 1px;
  padding: 45px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you set a background to the whole body, it will apply to the whole body…
And you can’t put a footer (or what so ever is displayed) outside the body.

I guess in your case I would create a div#pageContainer to put your page content, and apply the blue background to it with

```
div#pageContainer {
  background-image: url(image/blue.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLE5w/1/).